# Is the every translationally invariant operator constructed from powers of the Laplacian operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

Consider for simplicty 1d discrete chain - $x_1 \ldots x_n$, and let the field $\phi(x_i)$ reside on the sites of this chain.

Operators $\mathcal{O}$ in this this theory are hermitian $n \times n$ matrices.

Translationally invariant operators, those, which commute with the discrete translation operator $\mathcal{T}_i$ are the hermitian **Toeplitz** matrices (for periodic boundary conditions **circulant** matrices), those that depend only on the difference between the indices $i, j$ :
$$
\mathcal{O}_{ij} = \mathcal{O}_{i - j} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
o_0 & o_1 & o_2 \ldots \\
o_{-1} & o_0 & o_1 \ldots \\
\ldots & \ldots & o_0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In the coarsest discretization 1d Laplacian is a matrix with $(1 \ \  -2 \ \  1)$ on the diagonals, the matrix with the upper and lower bandwidth of 1. And each power of the Laplacian $\Delta_{1D}^{k}$ will have the bandwidths of $k$ for $k \leqslant n$. And these powers seem to form a basis in the space of hermitian Toeplitz matrices. So the general translationally invariant operator is some polynomial of $\Delta_{1D}^{k}$:
$$
\mathcal{O} = a_0 I + a_1 \Delta_{1D} + a_2 \Delta_{1D}^2 + \ldots
$$
I guess I am asking something trivial in a fancy formulation, but does this statement hold in the *continuous case*, where the operators act on infinite-dimensional space, and can this reasoning be generalized to higher dimensional spaces?

Comment: Doesn't this only give you the symmetric matrices Toeplitz matrices? To get the anti-symmetric ones you'd want to throw in the discrete derivative operator as well.

Comment: @jacob1729 with the forward and backward discrete derivative one may generate any toeplitz matrix, but they are not hermitian, and observables in QM are hermitian operators

Comment: I don't think it will extend to higher dimensions. The operators $\partial_x^2$ and $\partial_y^2$ are translation invariant and Hermitian, but can't be expressed in terms of the 2d Laplacian $\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2$. If you throw in rotation invariance though, then I might believe it.

Comment: @spiridon_the_sun_rotator why are we restricting to real matrices? I would have thought that $iD$ where $D$ is the discrete derivative $D_{ij}\sim \delta_{i,j+1}-\delta_{i+1,j}$
 is a perfectly good translationally invariant observable (the momentum) that is not a power of the Laplacian. So I think really the continuum generalisation would be "is every operator $[O,p]=0$ expressible as a power series in $p$?"

Comment: @jacob1729 you're right, also there is a symmetric discrete difference operator, which is Hermitian

Answer (score 1):

A formal wisecrack: The [shift matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices) $\Sigma_1$ goes to something like $T=e^{a\partial}$ in the continuum limit, so, yes, this commutes with all operators with only $\partial $s and no $x$s, like your expansion. There is a lot of fine print w.r.t. boundary conditions, but this fine print goes with taking the continuum limit...